# can not update UImageView's image in Custom UIview

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

it's my first time to ask question, if there's anything wrong, please tell me softly.:]

Here's my custom UIView, there's a UIImageView in it. I set its image and highlighted image. I wish i can change them when I pan on it. But it could not update image.

Thank you for reading, hope you can help me and others who facing the same problem like me.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TextStickerView: UIView {
    var defaultInset: CGFloat = 20
    var defaultMinimumSize: CGFloat {
        return defaultInset * 4
    }
    let buttonSize = CGSize(width: 45, height: 45)
    // Variables for moving view
    var beginPoint: CGPoint!
    var beginCenter: CGPoint!

    var moveBtn: UIImageView {
        let myView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: bottomLeftImageView.frame.origin.x + defaultInset / 3, y: CGRectGetMaxY(bottomLeftImageView.frame)), size: buttonSize))
        myView.image = UIImage(named: "text_move")
        myView.highlightedImage = UIImage(named: "text_move_down")
        myView.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(_:)))
        myView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        myView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        return myView
    }
    func handlePanGesture(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        print("pan")
        let touchLocation = recognizer.locationInView(self.superview)
        switch recognizer.state {
            case .Began:
                moveBtn.highlighted = true
                beginPoint = touchLocation
                beginCenter = self.center
                /// FIX: can not update moveBtn's image after set moveBtn.highlighted true
                setNeedsDisplay()
            case .Changed:
                self.center = CGPoint(x: beginCenter.x + (touchLocation.x - beginPoint.x), y: beginCenter.y + (touchLocation.y - beginPoint.y))
            case .Ended:
                self.center = CGPoint(x: beginCenter.x + (touchLocation.x - beginPoint.x), y: beginCenter.y + (touchLocation.y - beginPoint.y))
                moveBtn.highlighted = false
                setNeedsDisplay()


            default:
                break
        }
        init(contentView: UIView) {
        self.contentView = contentView
        self.contentView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: defaultInset, y: defaultInset)
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentView.frame.width + defaultInset * 2, height: contentView.frame.height + defaultInset * 2 + buttonSize.height)

        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.addSubview(self.moveBtn)
        self.moveBtn.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var moveBtn: UIImageView {` is a computing property. So every time you get it, you will get a new image view. Try this:

```
    var moveBtn: UIImageView = {
        let myView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: bottomLeftImageView.frame.origin.x + defaultInset / 3, y: CGRectGetMaxY(bottomLeftImageView.frame)), size: buttonSize))
        myView.image = UIImage(named: "text_move")
        myView.highlightedImage = UIImage(named: "text_move_down")
        myView.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(_:)))
        myView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        myView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        return myView
    }()
```

Comment: Thank you very much,Lumislxk.